# Deshabilitar un boton segun el contenido de un arraylist

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas estoy haciendo una aplicación en android studio, y en una parte creo varios edittext dinamicos según un intent de la pantalla anterior, y lo querria hacer es que el boton de comenzar, que inicia otro intent, solo se habilitara cuando se compruebe que todos los edidtext no estan vacios.
Cada vez que se crea un edittext es introducido en un arrayList por lo que pensé usar la función contains pero no se mu bien como seria.

```
 cant = Integer.parseInt(dato);

    ScrollView layout = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.linearJugadores);

    LinearLayout contenedor = new LinearLayout(this);
    contenedor.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    contenedor.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    final ArrayList<EditText> listaEdit = new ArrayList<EditText>();
    for (int j = 1; j <= cant; j++ ){
        EditText edit = new EditText(this);
        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        edit.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        edit.setId(j);
        edit.setMinWidth(200);
        text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        text.setText("\nJugador " + j);
        text.setId(j);
        contenedor.addView(text);
        contenedor.addView(edit);
        listaEdit.add(edit);

    }
  Button bEmpezar = new Button(this);
      bEmpezar.setText("Empezar partida");
      bEmpezar.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorNaranja);
      bEmpezar.setTextColor(R.color.colorBlanco);
      contenedor.addView(bEmpezar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera debido a que son muchos campos crea un método que valida por cada item del list si esta vacío de ser así retorna false en el método ejemplo:

De este manera tienes que pasar todos los EditText como parámetros
 del metodo, pero no seria lo mejor ya que tenidas que agregar manualmente cada EditText

```
public boolean validate(EditText... editTexts){

                                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTexts[0].getText())){
                                    editTexts[0].setError("Campo obligatorio");
                                    return false;
                                }

                                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTexts[1].getText())){
                                    editTexts[1].setError("Campo obligatorio");
                                    return false;
                                }

                                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTexts[2].getText())){
                                    editTexts[2].setError("Campo obligatorio");
                                    return false;
                                }

                                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTexts[3].getText())){
                                    editTexts[3].setError("Campo obligatorio");
                                    return false;
                                }

                                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTexts[4].getText())){
                                    editTexts[4].setError("Campo obligatorio");
                                    return false;
                                }
                                return true;
                            }
```

Esta seria la mejor manera en tu caso:

```
public boolean validateAll(ArrayList<EditText> editTexts){

                            for (EditText current : editTexts){
                                if  (TextUtils.isEmpty(current.getText())){
                                 current.setError("Campo requerido");  
                                 return false;
                                } else
                                    return true;
                        }
```

Por ejemplo puedes mostrar el botón si el método retorna true ejemplo:

**if(validateAll())
   tu_boton.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);**

Esta linea lo muestra en la pantalla en caso de que por defecto este con la propiedad **GONE**.

Si solo quieres desactivar la función pero que se muestre en la pantalla entonces usa la propiedad:

**tu_boton.setEnabled(true);**// o falso según el caso

}

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer condiciones:
if(EditTex!==null){
button.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
}

** INVISIBLE-- como su nombre lo dice lo pone invisible pero aun sigue estando ahí, a diferencia del (View.GONE) este hace que el item o en este caso tu boton desaparezca por completo.